# Optimized algorithm to synchronize two arrays

Tags: algorithm, merge

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to synchronize two arrays. Let's say a1 and a2 are two arrays given as input.

a1 - C , C++ , Java , C# , Perl

a2 - C++ , Python , Java , Cw , Haskel

Output 2 arrays:

Output A1: C , C++ , Java

Output A2: Cw , Haskell , Python

Output A1:

1) items common to both arrays
2) items only in A1 and not in A2

Output A2:

items only in a2

Thanks in advance.

Raj

Comment: Is there a particular programming language you are trying to do this in?

Comment: Why are there two parts to the output for A1?

Comment: @akonsu, there would be 50000 entries so IMHO linear search would not be optimal
@Ryan, java is fine... thot of using collections.. but not sure which is the best collection for such huge number of entries...

Comment: @ESRogs, the logic goes like this... 

with these details, am just doing a update on the db... from the set of old entries i delete which ones are not in the new list (1st criteria) .. and just add the new ones (2nd)...

Comment: @Raj: Note that `A1 = (a1 ∩ a2) ∪ (a1 \ a2) = a1`. I guess you rather want `A1 = a1 \ a2` (items to delete) and `A2 = a2 \ a1` (new items to add).

Comment: Yeah, as Gumbo points out, if A1 contains items that are in both a1 and a2, and it also contains items that are only in a1 but not in a2, then it contains exactly the same items as a1.

Comment: Is there a reason your sample output for A1 doesn't contain C# and Perl?  Aren't those included based on "2) items only in a1 and not in a2"?

Comment: @Gumbo, thanks for the precious hint, how blind I am! :-)

Comment: @Raj: Do the input arrays contain duplicates? Means: Could a1 be something like Java, C, Perl, C, Java, Basic or is every element unique in the array? If there are duplicates, you cannot use hash tables, otherwise there might be a quick solution using them.

Comment: @Ridicully, there are no duplicate entries in an array.. all are unique..

Answer (score 7):

1. Sort both arrays with an efficient sorting algorithm, complexity of O(n.log(n))
2. Build the output arrays initially empty
3. Compare the first element a1 of sorted A1 to the first element a2 of sorted A2

   - Equal means is in both arrays, put a1 into OutputA1
   - a1 < a2 means a1 is only in A1, a1 now necomes next element in sorted A1, put a1 into OutputA1
   - else a2 < a1 means a2 is only in A2, a2 now necomes next element in sorted A2, put a2 into OutputA2

Do this until you processed all elements in the sorted arrays, complexity of O(n).

Comment: thanks a lot jdehaan for replying.. :) is there a way to do this without sorting, because for 50K entries sorting might be a overhead..

Comment: sorting is O(n.log(n)), 50K is pretty manageable in arrays, do not worry. There is an intrinsic complexity in the problem you are trying to solve. If you don't have it with sorting, you'll transfer it to the part that has to check the elements. There is no magic solution.

Comment: I think the only potential way to do this faster than O(n*log(n)) would be to use a hash table.  Then you could get O(n) time, *if* you had a good hashing function.

Comment: But how would you figure out that an item is in A2 but not in A1 without some poor algorithm like linear search (for each item, what means O(n^2))?